# Programmatically access the App's icon on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, appicon

I want to send a Tweet from my App and for the actual tweet I want to include the App's icon.

Is there a quick way to access the icon. Otherwise I have add and duplicate the icon to my Resources folder in Xcode.

Comment: You're probably better off including a new icon specifically formatter for twitter to match dimension requirements etc - the answer below will still work, just use your twitter icon's filename instead!

Comment: @deanWombourne And why is that ? Would there be any problem if Icon.png is used ? Plz don't take it wrong but just curious to know.

Comment: No, no problem at all but what if the image they want is a slightly different resolution; they will scale your icon.png and it will look blurry. If you gave them the correct resolution image it would still be sharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app icons is already in the resource directory (which doesn't really exist)

```
UIImage *appIconImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"appicon.png"];
```

Where `appicon.png` is the name of you app's icon file.

Comment: I think it's icon.png not appicon.png

Comment: imageNamed instead of imageNames(rckoenes mis-spelled it)

Comment: That's up to you, you must ste the icon name in the `info.plist` there you can enter any name you want. We use `AppIcon.png`

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava thnx, did not see that typo.